# Why would "to center around" be illogical?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, logic

I have seen the discussions of "to center on" vs "to center around", and usually the argument is that "to center X around Y" is illogical. The counter-argument is generally that it is an idiom and therefore does not have to be logical. However, I do not see why this phrase is illogical.

To me, there are clearly to ways that "to center" can be used:

1. Putting X in the center of Y.
2. Putting the center of X on Y

The first meaning obviously doesn't make sense with "about". You can't center a picture around a page. But in the context of second meaning, I find it is perfectly logical to center X around Y, eg. "to center a circle around a point". "At" and "on" also make sense here, but so does "around".

So why is it necessary to invoke the argument of the idiom? Am I misunderstanding something?

-

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/centered-on-or-centered-around?lq=1). Most answers there just state it is illogical, not why. The few that do only say that it is illogical since to center X is to put X in the center, which is only the first meaning I mentioned. The answer of user *oosterwal* comes close but only talks about a set of multiple.

I would like to know **why** it is illogical to center for example a hullahoop around a candle, i.e. putting the candle in the center of the hullahoop.

Moreover, even the idiomatic use seems logical to me, since for example arguments centered around a main point seem more meant in this second meaning, rather than them being in the center of something.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate- that question asks whether it's illogical, this one asks why people consider it illogical. The other question just doesn't answer this one.

Comment: As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=argument+centres+on%2Cargument+centres+around%2Cargument+centers+on%2Cargument+centers+around&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cargument%20centres%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cargument%20centres%20around%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cargument%20centers%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cargument%20centers%20around%3B%2Cc0) shows, AmE has largely settled on ***centers on*** in recent decades, but ***centres around*** is still relatively common too - particularly in BrE (note the spelling difference in the chart).

Comment: ...I see nothing "illogical" in either preposition, and I *certainly* don't think there's any scope for talking about "grammatically correct" in this context.

Comment: @creative_name: I think it *is* a duplicate. All the answers to the original seem to reference the "logic" or "sense" of both forms, so I don't see why this question counts as something separate. OP could always post a comment asking for clarification on one of the original answers if there's highly specific aspect not explicitly covered.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The other question or its answers do not answer my question. I tried to clarify in an edit.

Comment: It centers around the fact that many people mistake English for mathematics.

Comment: An old TV ad used to describe Tootsie Roll Pops (a candy) as "a chewy chocolatey center surrounded by a hard candy shell." The candy was essentially a sphere on a paper stick, so if "centering around" applies to a Hula Hoop encircling a candle , it surely applies at least as well to a hard candy shell surrounding a nougat core; in other words, we would be logically justified in reframing the Tootsie Roll Pop description as "a hard candy shell centered around a chewy chocolatey center." It's the notion of something "centering around a center"  that seems logically problematic. ...

Comment: ... The effect is a bit like the effect of saying "focusing around a focus" or "targeting around a target." If either of those phrases were idiomatic in English, most people wouldn't find fault with them as a matter of logic—because in an existential sense, usage justifies itself—but because they aren't idiomatic, we hold them to a stricter logical standard. The notion of "centering on a center," in contrast, seems merely redundant—not illogical.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example only works with the word *circle*, because it is contextually known that a circle is *drawn around* something. So it is perhaps not illogical when the thing you're centring around a point is itself round (and around a centre). It could be considered a contamination of *revolve around* / *drawn around* with *centred on*, though.

But I don't think it works logically with other shapes, like centring a legion around a flag: it would mean that the centre of the legion is a circular shape, and that this circular centre lies around the flag. That doesn't make sense (although of course it can be supported by idiomaticity).

Another point: I think *centring a circle around a point* is pleonastic, because a circle is already necessarily *around* something, so you're saying the same thing twice when you say a circle is centred around a point.

Comment: I don't understand why it would not work for other shapes. Centering a legion around a flag seems to make perfect sense to me. I don't see what the shape of the legion's center itself has to do with it.

I could also imagine centering a (rectangular) frame around a mural ... No?

Centering a circle around a point is not pleonastic, I meant centering it around a specific point, eg. around the corner of a square.

Comment: @LuKas: I think the basic fact that you can replace *around* with a non-round preposition (like *on*) is evidence that the roundness of *around* was pleonastic? Otherwise, *around* would add something to the sentence. After some more thinking, I think is the root of the problem, and my legion is an extension of it.